# Can we use TestCafe for Automating angular or reactjs application?

Tags: angularjs, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Can we use an open-source TestCafe for automating Angular and React applications? Is it possible to handle redirects in TestCafe? Can we add sleep in a test when a 3 seconds load is not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Testcafe interacts with the website, not the framework itself.
You can, of course, use [framework-specific selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/framework-specific-selectors.html) if you wish. You can pause the test using

```js
testcafe.wait(timeoutMs)
```

or simply extend the timeout for waiting mechanism (either change the default one in the test runner or pass one for a specific selector as an option)